# Module not found error with multiprocessing when called from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm starting to include multiprocessing into my code, as the task I'm trying to automate is rather costly computationally speaking. The module structure in the code I have is the following, based on the stackoverflow information I've been gathering. I'm working on python 3.7 in Win10.

**main**: where the multiprocessing function is called, besides loading inputs and such.

```
import pandas as pd
import run

def do():
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Identifier': ['id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_3', 'id_3', 'id_3', 'id_3'],
                 'float_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 25, 33, 45, 50, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5],
                 'a': np.random.rand(15),
                 'b': np.random.rand(15),
                 'c': np.random.rand(15)})
    
    v_column=['a', 'b', 'c']
    
    df_out=run.function_multiprocessing(df, v_column)

    return df_out

if __name__=='__main__':
    df_out=do()
```

- **run**: where the multiprocessing function is located

```
import defs
import pandas as pd

import multiprocessing


def iterator(data, id_col, value_col):
    for col in value_col:
        yield (data[col].values, data[id_col].values)

def function_multiprocessing(data, v_column):
    list_df=[]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for identifier, df_f in data.groupby(['Identifier']): 
            print(identifier)
            data_f=pool.starmap(defs.function_to_apply, iterator(df_f, 'float_id', v_column))
            
            out=pd.DataFrame(data_f, index=[identifier])
            list_df.append(out)
    
    df_out=pd.concat(list_df)
    
    return df_out
```

- **defs**: where the function to "multiprocess" (*function_to_apply*) is located

None of these modules belong to my PYHTONPATH, and are located in the same folder. What I'm trying to do is apply a function over each "Identifier", based on the values found in "float_id" and the values of columns "a", "b" and "c" respectively. We may think of a weighted average of the column values based on the "float_id" values for the sake of simplicity.

When I execute the code, I get the following error -no matter what I try-, over and over again for each worker.

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defs'
```

I've tried including the line `multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")` after importing the multiprocessing module, which raised an error. The same for `"spawn"`. I also tried including the module "defs" as a parameter in the `function_multiprocessing` method, and calling it from `main`, with no success. The same error occurs when providing "function_to_apply" as a parameter.

¿What am I doing wrong?¿How could I make this work?

Thanks a lot beforehand!

**UPDATE**: When importing the `defs.py` module within the `function_multiprocessing` method as such

```
def function_multiprocessing(data, v_column):
    import defs
    
    list_df=[]
    ...
```

it does not raise any errors. However, when providing the module as a variable it did not work.

Comment: File `defs.py` then needs to be in the same directory as the "main" program. If `main.py`, `run.py` and `defs.py` are all in the same folder, then I do not understand how you would get this error since the directory in which the "main" program exists, i.e. the directory which has `main.py` in this case, is automatically prepended to `sys.path`.

Comment: @Booboo, all of the files are located in the same directory. When using the ```ThreadPool``` class instead of the ```Pool``` class, the error does not arise anymore, although the computation time does not seem to vary from when the code is executed linearly.

Comment: I just saw your update. By moving the import to inside `function_multiprocessing`, it will not be executed by the sub-processes. I don't think it's really a "module not found error" *per se* but rather code at global scope that is in `defs` that is being executed that is generating an error.

Comment: @Booboo, thanks a lot for the quick answer! Do you think there is a way to not import the module inside the function, but being able to execute it? I believe that this solution would not be the preferred option best-practice wise.

Comment: Well, I am only guessing about the problem. Have you looked at `defs` to see if in fact there is executable code that might throw an exception when re-executed by a sub-process? Is the file small enough to post? If it turns out that it does have such code that can't *easily* be modified, I don't really see anything *too* wrong with your solution.

Comment: @Booboo, the ```defs.py``` module contains a minimization problem, which uses scipy.minimize, pandas and functions defined within the module, being function_multiprocessing the main one. It does not have any additional dependencies. The code is pretty straight-forward, but rather large to post here. Could you imagine any of these modules generating the said dependency? Thanks one more time for your time.

Comment: If it just contains function *declarations*, then I don't see that as a problem. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error. A workaround is to call `subprocess.run` directly in `map` (which is similar to `starmap`, but here we can't use that, as it would unpack arguments for `subprocess.run` instead of "main_script" below), with your executable logic in a python file - as opposed to a function:

```
pool.map(subprocess.run, [sys.executable, main_script, *args])
```

Where

- sys.executable givese you your python executable
- main_script is a string which holds the full path to a python file, where the code inside
  `if __name__ == '__main__':`
  will be executed. You can put your logic from your `function_to_apply` there.
- args: optionally given arguments, that you can parse as if they were command line arguments to this script. If you don't need this, you can omit this from the list above.